# A linear Transformation that maps the nonnegative orthant to the entire space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Can we find a linear transformation 
$T : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that 
$\{Tx | x \ge 0\} = \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: What does $x\geqslant0$ means when $x\in\mathbb R^n$? What is an orthant?

Comment: Maybe that's a rather particular way to denote the orthant $\;\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in\Bbb R^n\;|\;,\;\;x_1\ge0\;\forall i\}\;$ ...

Comment: $x \ge 0$ means $x_1 \ge 0$, $x_2 \ge 0$, \cdots, $x_n \ge 0$

Comment: Did you try to achieve that first with $\;R^1\cong \Bbb R\;$ , with $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ and etc.?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. But I could not find any linear mapping. I have tried with $x \mapsto \tan x$, but it will not work since we need $T$ linear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that a mapping $T$ with the above properties exists. Then $T$ is surjective, hence $ker(T)=\{0\}.$

Now let $w \in \mathbb R^n$ and $w \ne 0$. Then there exist unique determined $u,v \ge 0$ such that $Tu=w$ and $Tv=-w.$

This gives $u+v \in ker(T)$, hence $v=-u$. Since $u,v \ge 0$, we get $u=v=0$ and therefore $w=0$, a contradiction.